# Are the latest Oracle 12c Release 2 JDBC driver and UCP available via maven?

Tags: oracle12c, ojdbc

Oracle corporation released a new version 12.2.0.1 of their JDBC driver, for Oracle Database 12c Release 2.

The JAR files can be manually downloaded from this location: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html

**But are these JAR files available through the Oracle Maven repository** at maven.oracle.com?

I setup my build originally following this Oracle Blog: [Get Oracle JDBC drivers and UCP from Oracle Maven Repository (without IDEs)](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc) and have the ojdbc7.jar and ucp.jar as dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I want to upgrade to the new ojdbc8.jar and latest ucp.jar but don't know the coordinates (and maven.oracle.com does not provide browsing). I could not resolve "com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1" or "com.oracle.jdbc:ucp:12.2.0.1".

Comment: it's there now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

12.2.0.1 JDBC driver and UCP are available on Oracle Maven Repository. 
You can use the GAV details below to download the same.

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>12.2.0.1</version> 
</dependency>

 <dependency> 
   <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
   <version>12.2.0.1</version> 
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I got the message : 'Could not resolve dependencies for project gov.dgr:Proyect:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1 in spring-milestone (https://repo.spring.io/milestone) -> [Help 1]' The Help1 link is: https://cwiki.apache.org//confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Does Someone get the same message?

Answer (score 1):

I asked this in a (private) Service Request with Oracle and got the following answer from them last week:

> [...]
>   We still haven’t uploaded the 12.2 JDBC driver on Oracle Maven.
>   We will do it in a few weeks.
>   [...]

I'll update this answer as soon as I get hold of the GAV parameters.

Comment: No, my SR never got updated. But you can use the one's provided by the accepted answer, they are correct.

Comment: thanks, i am able to download the ojdc8 from oracle maven repo.