# Acquiring JDBC connection under maven's REST service

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

I'm currently [poking](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/griz_jersey_intro/Grizzly-Jersey-Intro.html#section2) the REST servers with maven's help(jersey-grizzly2-quickstart archetype, nothing posh). And apparently I'm doing something wrong in terms of library management since I can't acquire JDBC connection inside the service. It throws "No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@..." at me. Meanwhile I can connect to this database from a regular java app just fine. I'm fairly clueless about how to track down the root of the problem... Dependency to ojdbc7 is specified within pom.xml file as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which looks legit. It can be a simple version collision, but as I said, Im clueless on how to properly check on these things...

As for reproduction steps:
1) within some dummydirectory ask maven to

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.example.rest -DartifactId=jersey-service -Dpackage=com.example.rest -DarchetypeVersion=2.17
```

2) add

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@144.21.77.27:1521:orcl", "", "");
```

string to MyResource class generated by maven (Connection and DriverManager from javax.ws.rs library package, this database is my sandbox playground within oracle cloud).
3) Then run the server with

```
mvn clean compile

mvn exec:java
```

4) witness the problem yourself (on page access it returns "No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@...")

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Is the Oracle JDBC driver available in your Maven repo? This jar is not available via Maven central.

Comment: @werner, as you might have guessed, I'm blind when it comes down to Maven... Having hard time understanding it. If I get your point - it just can't download specified dependency file, right? I wonder how can one tell if it succeeds or fails(w/o deep knowledge)... Apparently this file is relevant to oracle maven repository which requires some extra work to be accessed. Perhaps it would solve my problem. Heres the topic I'm about to dig into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886636/are-the-latest-oracle-12c-release-2-jdbc-driver-and-ucp-available-via-maven
wonder if that would help...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so thing was obviously about Maven not having an appropriate library. Too bad I'm clueless about debugging problems with Maven. [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886636/are-the-latest-oracle-12c-release-2-jdbc-driver-and-ucp-available-via-maven) did properly guide me to the end. It finally works now :>